# Derive minimum positive rate of change for co2 data

Tags: time-series, dataset, validation

I have CO2 (in parts per million) data of a closed room. The CO2 data is recorded along with timestamps. Typical difference between two samples is around five minutes.
**My aim is to find occupancy of the room.** 
Theoretically, while the room is occupied the CO2 levels increase. And, when the room is unoccupied - CO2 levels decrease.  So, I take 1st derivative of CO2 data with respect to time which gives me rate of change in CO2. At this stage, I judge the room to be occupied with positive rate of change (rate of change > 0) in CO2 and not occupied otherwise.
I have some other CO2 data as well where I don't have validation head-counts. I use the same above approach to analyze this data and I believe there are many false positives in results (I have validation data of the room with actual Boolean head-counts) corresponding lower positive rate of change. The thought behind false positives being certainly there is because I know for sure the room was unoccupied for those particular duration.

I want to derive a positive cutoff from training data (the one with validation set) so that I can apply the same approach on new data without any validation set being present. The room will be judged to be occupied when (**rate of change** > **positive_cutoff**). This can decrease the number of false positives in results.

Have a look sample graphs:

Smooth CO2 (Data with validation set) :[image]
Results after rate of change analysis: [image]
CO2 data without validation set : [image]
Results after rate of change analysis on above data : [image]

Now, I realize that for all actual occupancies, the rate of change is significantly higher than zero. Hence, the idea of deriving a positive threshold from training data (co2 values + actual headcounts) and use that threshold for predicting occupancy of room in test data.

How should I approach the problem from here on?

Comment: Post some actual data? With info when the room was in fact occupied?